# rmarkdown subtitle formatting when rendering to markdown

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I'm trying to render the following Rmarkdown document to markdown.

```
---
title: "title"
author: "daniel"
date: "24-08-2015"
output:
  md_document:
    variant: markdown+backtick_code_blocks-fenced_code_attributes

---

## A

## Á
```

I need those markdown variants to format code chunks when rendering to markdown.
But some problems  arise when using them.

When I `render("test.Rmd")`

I got the following result:

```
---
author: daniel
date: '24-08-2015'
output:
  md_document:
    variant: 'markdown+backtick\_code\_blocks-fenced\_code\_attributes'
title: title
...

A
-

Á {#a}
-
```

But I expected this to be:

```
---
author: daniel
date: '24-08-2015'
output:
  md_document:
    variant: 'markdown+backtick\_code\_blocks-fenced\_code\_attributes'
title: title
...

A
-

Á
-
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: I think it works using `knitr::knit()`. As `rmarkdown::render` calls `knitr::knit` in this case (Rmd file), it may be something inside `rmarkdown::render` function

Comment: Hmm `knitr::knit` does not replace the `_` by `\_`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `-header_attributes` extension to the "variant" option

```
---
title: "title"
author: "daniel"
date: "24-08-2015"
output:
  md_document:
    variant: markdown+backtick_code_blocks-fenced_code_attributes-header_attributes

---

## A

## Á
```

This is not necessary most of the times because we often use markdown_strict variant.

More information:

http://pandoc.org/demo/example9/pandocs-markdown.html

and search `header_attributes`.